# Gravity Forms Wordpress Plugin Blank

Tags: wordpress

I installed the Gravity Forms plugin for my WP site, but keep getting a blank screen when trying to embed the form.  I've tried both the shortcode style and the PHP style.  Any ideas as to what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try disabling conditional formatting on any of the questions in your form.